# Hexadecimal comparison for big number in c program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

long long int A =  0xAABBCCDDBBCCFFEE;
long long int B = 0xAACCCCDDBBDDFF00;
int array[8] = {'\0'};
int byte_compare(int A, int B)
{
  int i = 0;
  long long int j = 0xFF;
  long long int C = A;
  long long int D = B;

  while(i < 8)
  {
    C = (j & A);
    D = (j & B);
    printf("C = %x\n",C);
    printf("D = %x\n",D);
    printf("j = %x\n",j);
    if(C == D)
    {
        array[i] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
    i++;
    j = j << 8;
  }
}

main()
{
    int i = 0;
    byte_compare(A,B);
    while(i < 8)
    {
        printf("array[%d] - %d\n",i, array[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

long long int A = 0xAABBCCDDBBCCFFEE;
long long int B = 0xAACCCCDDBBDDFF00;
result = 10111010
```

when A and B byte number matches with each other it should print 1 otherwise 0.

for my above program it is printing output

```
C = ee
D = 0
j = ff
C = ff00
D = ff00
j = ff00
C = cc0000
D = dd0000
j = ff0000
C = bb000000
D = bb000000
j = ff000000
C = 0
D = 0
j = 0
C = 0
D = 0
j = 0
C = 0
D = 0
j = 0
C = 0
D = 0
j = 0
array[0] - 0
array[1] - 1
array[2] - 0
array[3] - 1
array[4] - 1
array[5] - 1
array[6] - 1
array[7] - 1
```

Not able to compare after first four byte please help me what datatype I should use instead above.

Comment: `long long int A =  0xAABBCCDDBBCCFFEE;` ----> `unsigned long long int A =  0xAABBCCDDBBCCFFEE;`

Comment: `int byte_compare(long long int A, long long int B) {`

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems in your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void byte_compare(uint64_t C, uint64_t D, int *array)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 8)
    {
        printf("C = %"PRIx64"\n"  , (C&0xFF));
        printf("D = %"PRIx64"\n\n", (D&0xFF));

        if ((C&0xFF) == (D&0xFF))
        {
            array[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            array[i] = 0;
        }

        i++;

        C >>= 8;
        D >>= 8;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    uint64_t A = UINT64_C(0xAABBCCDDBBCCFFEE);
    uint64_t B = UINT64_C(0xAACCCCDDBBDDFF00);

    int array[8] = {0};

    byte_compare(A, B, array);

    while (i < 8)
    {
        printf("array[%d] - %d\n", i, array[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

1. Correct type for your variables must be `unsigned long long` due to the literals: bit 63 is set to 1 so assign it to a signed variable causes overflow which invoke [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Using `stdint.h` standard header you can use `uint64_t` that is clearer.
2. `byte_compare` function definition is wrong, you must pass parameters with correct type: `unsigned long long` (`uint64_t`). Moreover the function does not return an int so should be `void`.
3. `printf` with `%x` format specifier wants an `unsigned int`, not a `uint64_t`. Best thing to do is to use defined in `inttypes.h` standard header where all format specifier are well reported: in your case `PRIx64` is the right one.
4. In your version of code you are left shifting a `long long int` that is used as mask to "select" the byte to check. It is plain wrong because last shift causes an overflow on a `signed` value that is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as for point 1.
5. `stdint.h` has also macros that append the correct suffix to literals.

Another example using a mask:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void byte_compare(uint64_t C, uint64_t D, int *array)
{
    uint64_t mask = UINT64_C(0xFF00000000000000);

    while (mask > 0)
    {
        printf("C = %"PRIx64"\n"  , (C&mask));
        printf("D = %"PRIx64"\n\n", (D&mask));

        if ((C&mask) == (D&mask))
        {
            *array = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            *array = 0;
        }

        mask >>= 8;
        array--;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    uint64_t A = UINT64_C(0xAABBCCDDBBCCFFEE);
    uint64_t B = UINT64_C(0xAACCCCDDBBDDFF00);

    int array[8] = {0};

    byte_compare(A, B, &array[7]);

    while (i < 8)
    {
        printf("array[%d] - %d\n", i, array[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```